# How can I code Android with J2ME?

Tags: android, java-me, midp

As for as I know that android application can be developed in core java only. But is it possible to code android with J2ME? Please give some example codes if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [Android J2ME MIDP RUNNER](http://www.netmite.com/android/):

> This is a Android J2ME MIDP RUNNER so
>   that *ANY* J2ME  or MIDP applications
>   can run without modification.

So theoretically, you just create your J2ME application and that will ensure that it runs.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using the Android framework to create applications for it. The J2ME runner is a work in progress and will always be a work in progress. Google is not going to ensure that this J2ME project is supported in future releases and it may just stop working with any firmware update.

Keeping this issue aside, you are better off using the vastly different and better application elements that Android provides than being restricted to what is provided using this J2ME runner.

Answer (score 1):

The open source license of www.microemu.org seems to indicate that you can even include its code into a commercial application.